# Python Syntax: Subprocess Call PostgreSQL Query, "Error: Only ASCII Characters Allowed"

Tags: python, postgresql, subprocess, postgresql-9.3

I'm working with the following code in python, calling a PostgreSQL query with `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
claimer_name = 'a_name'
startdate = '2014-04-01'
enddate = '2018-04-01' 

data = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/psql -U user_name "SELECT c.asset_id, c.video_id,
c.claim_id, c.claim_date FROM db.claim c JOIN db.claim_history h ON c.claim_id = h.claim_id JOIN
db.users_email e ON LOWER(e.email) = LOWER(h.email) JOIN m.auth_user u ON e.user_id = u.id WHERE
h.list_order = 1 AND c.claim_origin = ‘Descriptive Search’ AND c.claim_date >= \"%s\" AND    
c.claim_date < \"%s\" AND concat(u.first_name, concat(chr(32),
u.last_name)) = \"%s\""' % (startdate, enddate, claimer_name)], shell=True)
```

How can I escape the single quotes around 'Descriptive Search'?  Running this code as-is gives the error `Only ASCII characters are allowed in an identifier.`

I have tried:

1. `[''Descriptive Search'']`
2. `[\'Descriptive Search\']`
3. `[""Descriptive Search""]`
4. `[concat('Descriptive', concat(chr(32), 'Search'))]`

and assigning a variable: `i = 'Descriptive Search'`, and then `c.claim_origin = \"%s\"`.

However, these attempts yield the same `ASCII characters` error.  Using string-formatting works fine for my other variables (`startdate`, `enddate`, `claimer_name`) and I'm stumped as to why it doesn't work for the string 'Descriptive Search'.

Using PostgreSQL 9.3.

Any help or points in the right direction would be great; thanks!

Comment: Egad. There are sooo many possible points of failure. Please please do yourself a favour and use a PostgreSQL driver library for Python, something like [Psycopg2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial). Going through shell is bound to give you a headache, if it hasn't already. And while you're at it, read about little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: +1 for **showing your code** and the **exact error text**. Good on you. In future please include the PostgreSQL version too, but +1 good question.

Comment: Thanks for the note, @CraigRinger!  will do for next time.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, I see you did add a version tag. Better to just put it in the text unless it's a particularly version-specific issue. Yes, I know, stack overflow is full of weird things like that.

Comment: Gotcha, @CraigRinger; thanks for the pro tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are so many things wrong with this.

- You should be using [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/) rather than trying to shell out to `psql` to talk to the database;
- Because you're not using a proper database binding you can't use placement parameters (prepared statements) properly, so you have to handle escaping in literals yourself to avoid [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) risks and quoting bugs;
- When invoking commands via `subprocess`, avoid using the shell if at all possible. It's another point of possible failure, and completely unnecessary in this case;
- Long strings should generally be `"""` quoted in Python to avoid the need to escape nested `"`s;
- The expression `concat(u.first_name, concat(chr(32), u.last_name))` is needlessly contorted. Just write `u.first_name || ' ' || u.last_name` or `format('%s %s', u.first_name, u.last_name)`;
- You're using `"double quotes"` to quote literals you substitute in, which is invalid SQL. They'll get treated as identifiers, per the documentation. So `c.claim_date < \"%s\"` will fail with an error like `no column "2014-04-01"`;
- You're using real single quotes, not apostrophes, when quoting `‘Descriptive Search‘`. At a guess you've edited the code in a word processor, not a programmer's text editor. You want apostrophes, `'Descriptive Search'`, when quoting literals in SQL.

Because you used single quote characters (U+2018) instead of apostrophes (U+0027) to quote the literal string `Descriptive Search`, PostgreSQL didn't recognise it as a literal and tried to parse it as an identifier. However, `‘` isn't a legal character in an unquoted identifier, so it reported the error you show.

See [the documentation on identifiers and literals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

Here's what you should have done:

```
import psycopg2
import datetime
claimer_name = 'a_name'
startdate = datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)
enddate = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)

conn = psycopg2.connect("user=user_name")
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("""
    SELECT 
        c.asset_id,
        c.video_id,
        c.claim_id,
        c.claim_date
    FROM db.claim c 
         JOIN db.claim_history h ON c.claim_id = h.claim_id 
         JOIN db.users_email e ON LOWER(e.email) = LOWER(h.email) 
         JOIN m.auth_user u ON e.user_id = u.id 
    WHERE h.list_order = 1 
      AND c.claim_origin = 'Descriptive Search'
      AND c.claim_date >= %s 
      AND c.claim_date < %s
      AND u.first_name || ' ' || u.last_name = %s
    """, (startdate, enddate, claimer_name)
)
results = curs.fetchall()
```

Pay particular attention the fact that I did *not* use Python's `%` string-formatting operator above. The `%s` entries are placement parameters that're substituted properly by psycopg2; see [passing parameters to SQL queries](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: Thanks for all of this, @CraigRinger!  It all makes sense and is very helpful.